# How to remove error in below verilog statement while running for ise simulator?

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I wrote few lines of code and it is giving error. The code is below:

```
module tb();  
wire [7:0] m1,m2,m3;   
reg [7:0] a,b,c;   
reg en;     
reg clka=0;   
s_three call(m1,m2,m3,a,b,c,en,clka);   
always begin   
 #10 clka<=~clka;        
end      

initial begin    
en<=1'b1;    
a<=8'h00;   
b<=8'haf;   
c<=8'ha2;   
end     
endmodule
```

---

```
module s_three(m1,m2,m3,a,b,c,en,clka);                                              
input [7:0] a,b,c;                       
input en,clka;                            
output [7:0] m1,m2,m3;               
wire [7:0] m11,m12;                          
s1 s0(m11,m12,a,b,en,clka);                      
endmodule
```

The error given below:

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:329 - "tb.v" Line 29. Concurrent assignment to a
>   non-net a is not permitted
>
> ERROR:Simulator:778 - Static elaboration of top level Verilog design
>   unit(s) in library work failed

How can I resolve it ?
Thank you

Comment: Sorry the mention line no 29 is `s_three call(m1,m2,m3,a,b,c,en,clka);` This the line in which it is pointing the error.

Comment: And what is the module declaration for ```s_three```? (i.e. what are the inputs and outputs)

Comment: You show the definition for a module called `s_three_1`, but in your testbench, you instantiate a module called `s_three` -- giving it an instance name of `call`, which is confusing at best.

Comment: it was s_three ... I corrected Can you have idea how can i remove the error as i post ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, so what is happening is you have declared your module as this:

```
module s_three(m1,m2,m3,a,b,c,en,clka);                                              
input [7:0] a,b,c;                       
input en,clka;                            
output [7:0] m1,m2,m3;               
wire [7:0] m11,m12;
```

Now you might expect the ports to be connected in the order they appear in the brackets, but this is actually not so, they need to be connected in the order they are declared by the `input ...`, `output ...` lines, i.e. the implicit connection order for your module will actually be:

```
s_three call(a,b,c,en,clk,m1,m2,m3)
```

As a result you are connecting up your ports in a way you aren't expecting which can lead to funny errors. In this case outputs are connected to inputs, the register `c` is connected to an output (bad!), etc.

---

Implicit connection of ports is a debugging headache and while it saves a little bit of typing you really should avoid it for your own sanity when it comes to testing things. Also if you happened to want to add a new port, or change them around later on, anything that is implicitly connected would break.

To solve the problem, you should use explicit connections. For example the following explicitly connects the pins:

```
s_three call(.m1(m1),.m2(m2),.m3(m3),.a(a),.b(b),.c(c),.en(en),.clka(clk));
```

The connections are described as: `.portInModule(signalToConnect)`. By doing it this way it doesn't matter what order they appear. This would work just as well:

```
s_three call(.clka(clk),.en(en),.a(a),.b(b),.c(c),.m1(m1),.m2(m2),.m3(m3));
```